# Showing a list in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem showing a list in kivy. I don't know how why don't show this two entries.
I think is something about how i pass my data, do I have to specify the columns or how to display the information. Am I passing wrong the data needed in recycleView?

My code.

My interchange.kv

```
<Button>
    color: .8,.9,0,1
    font_size: 16

<LeLayaout>:
    rows: 3
    cols: 1
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: 1,.05
        Button:
            text: 'Generate'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,"center_y":.5}
    BoxLayout:
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: 1,.05
        Button:
            text: 'Add person'
            pos_hint: {'x':0,'y':0}
            size_hint:.5,1
        Button:
            text: 'Remove person'
            pos_hint: {'x':.5,'y':0}
            size_hint:.5,1
```

My main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

# Before windows creation let's fix a size
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')

import json

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = {"Hector": "hector@pm.me","Pancho": "Pancho@pm.me"}

class LeLayaout(GridLayout):
    pass

class InterchangeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LeLayaout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    InterchangeApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems with your code:

- You define an `RV` class, but you never use it
- The `data` that you define in the `__init__()` method of the `RV` class is a dictionary, but the data is expected to be a list of dictionaries. See [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.data).
- The keys of the data dictionaries must be properties of the `viewclass`, but your keys are peoples names.
- You have not specified a `viewclass` for the `RV`.

To fix this change the `BoxLayout` in your `kv` to `RV`, and add a `viewclass`:

```
RV:
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Then change the `data` keys to contain properties of the `viewclass`:

```
class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{"text": "hector@pm.me"}, {"text": "Pancho@pm.me"}]
```

This may not be what you intended, but you can define your own `viewclass` and give it any properties that you need, as well as defining how it will display those properties.